# How to change url rendering another view from action?

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app

**This is my action:**

```
public function actionRend()
{
    $model = new RentForm();
    $parameter = Yii::$app->request->get('id');
    $query = Cars::findOne(['description' => $parameter]);
    $query = Car_rend_tariffs::find()->where(['car' => $query->id])->all();
    $rend = [];
    $i=0;
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
        $seconds = strtotime($model->start_time);
        $seconds_2 = strtotime($model->end_time);
        $seconds = ($seconds_2 - $seconds)/3600;
        $seconds = ceil($seconds);
        if ($seconds < 1) {
            $error_message = "Время аренды не может быть меньше часа";
            return $this->render('rend',[
            'model' => $model,
            'seconds' => $seconds,
            'error' => $error_message
            ]);
        }
        $query = Cars::findOne(['description' => $parameter]);
        $query_rent = Car_rend_time::find()->where('min_use_time <= :min_use_time and max_use_time >= :max_use_time',['min_use_time' => $seconds,'max_use_time' => $seconds])->one();
        $query_tariff = Car_rend_tariffs::findOne(['car' => $query->id,'car_rend_time' => $query_rent->id]);
        $tariff_view = Car_rend_tariff_views::findOne(['id' => $query_tariff->tariff]);
        $sum = $tariff_view->min_cost + ($seconds - $query_rent->min_use_time)*$tariff_view->additional_hour_cost;
        $payment = new PaymentForm();
        return $this->render('payment',[
            'model' => $payment,
            'service' => $query_tariff,
            'sum' => $sum
        ]);
    }
    return $this->render('rend',[
        'model' => $model
    ]);
}
```

**These are UrlManager rules in my config:**

```
'urlManager' => [
    'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            '' => 'main/default/index',
            '<_a:error>' => 'main/default/<_a>',
            '<_a:(login|logout)>' => 'admin/default/<_a>',
            '<_a:(admin)>' => 'admin/default/login',
            '<_a:(flight)>' => 'main/service/flight',
            '<_a:(auto)>' => 'main/service/auto',
            '<_a:(rend)>' => 'main/service/rend',
            '<_a:(payment)>' => 'main/service/payment',

            '<_m:[\w\-]+>/<_c:[\w\-]+>/<id:\d+>' => '<_m>/<_c>/view',
            '<_m:[\w\-]+>/<_c:[\w\-]+>/<_a:[\w\-]+>/<id:\d+>' => '<_m>/<_c>/<_a>',
            '<_m:[\w\-]+>' => '<_m>/default/index',
            '<_m:[\w\-]+>/<_c:[\w\-]+>' => '<_m>/<_c>/index',
        ],
],
```

Comment: Please post your code with proper formating

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37817063/how-to-change-url-rendering-view-from-another-action